# Unable to start/stop compute instance through azure machine learning using python

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to save a little money by starting/stopping AML compute instance using python. However, I'm having a bit of trouble after following instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-manage-compute-instance?tabs=python).

The instructions indicate that the following code should work using Python SDK azure-ai-ml v2:

```
ml_client.compute.begin_stop(ci_basic_name).wait()
```

However, I get the following error:

> "message": "StopCompute is not supported for 'AmlCompute' computes."

If anyone has had this issue and has a work around, I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A compute instance will be considered Inactive if there are:

No active Jupyter Kernel sessions

No active Jupyter terminal sessions

No actively running AML runs/experiments

Note that the above signals will include VS Code usage and AML Interactive Notebooks usage. There are some basic bounds around inactivity time periods; CI must be inactive for a minimum of 15 mins and a maximum of 24 hours (1440 mins).

There are multiple interfaces to configure this setting:
[image]

Comment: This code snippet does not work. Also, your import is wrong. Is this a chatgpt solution?

Comment: You can do through the UI.