# How to start the compute associated with my ML Studio Workspace in Azure, using the Python sdk?

Tags: azure, ml-studio

I've looked through lots of documentation online, but it all seems to discuss how to create and delete compute in Azure.

I already have a compute instance set up in my ML Workspace that I want to start via a python script. I don't want to click a button on the web portal.

Does anyone have some advice? Thank you.

I have tried lots of resources including [Unable to start/stop compute instance through azure machine learning using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75118127/unable-to-start-stop-compute-instance-through-azure-machine-learning-using-pytho) and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-compute-instance?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start or stop the compute instence from python SDK you can use `ComputeInstance` Class from  `azureml.core.compute`.

Below is a sample code snippet to do this:

```py
from  azureml.core.compute  import  ComputeTarget, ComputeInstance
from  azureml.core  import  Workspace

ws=Workspace.from_config()
compute_name="compute_name"
instance = ComputeInstance(workspace=ws, name=compute_name)
#To start
instance.start(wait_for_completion=True, show_output=True)
#To stop
instance.stop(wait_for_completion=True, show_output=True)
```

[image]
[image]

For more details, please refer to this [documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/v1/how-to-create-manage-compute-instance.md).